# Atualizando Tabela Mysql em uma determinada Hora

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Boa tarde,

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, tenho bloqueios na minha aplicação em PHP com Codeingniter, e preciso liberar os usuários algumas vezes. Então, seto meu usuário para 2(Supervisor) porém quero que no dia seguinte, às 8am ele volte a ser 1(usuário).

Tentei fazer m JS com setTimeout, porem para a aplicação funcionar eu teria que está na pagina... Queria fazer isso de modo dinâmico, li sobre evento do MySql, porém não fiquei meio confuso com seu funcionamento.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficarei muito grato!

Comment: porque nao cria um script in corre com o `cronjob`?

Comment: Como seria isso ?

Comment: *"Tentei fazer m JS com setTimeout"* você quer atualizar algo no servidor usando um evento do cliente, no navegador? nisso não faz sentido, fora se o navegador deveria continuar aberto. Por que não usa `CREATE EVENT` e cria um evento no banco de dados para fazer isso?

Comment: @RicardoPontual outra duvida, apenas fazendo o CREAT EVENT e colocando como EVERY 8 DAY_HOUR, ele vai executar todos os dias neste mesmo horario? Ou preciso fazer mais algo?

Comment: depois que criar o evento o "MySQL Event Scheduler" é responsável por executar de acordo com o schedule que foi programado, então estando funcionando vai sempre disparar o evento naquela hora todos os dias.

Comment: Creio que meu plano no Hostgator não faça isso...

Comment: tem de consultar eles para confirmar, mas se está executando o serviço do banco deve ter o serviço de eventos, precisa ver se é compartilhado e como configurar

Comment: Consegui usando o serviço de agendamento cron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fica claro assim ??

```
CREATE EVENT nome_do_evento
        ON SCHEDULE
          EVERY 8 DAY_HOUR
         COMMENT 'faz algo as  8:00 am todos os dias'
        DO
          UPDATE tabela SET coluna = valor ...
```

Comment: Eu consigo mesclar isso com uma Trigger? Para apenas executar essa função caso eu tenha feito uma modificação na tabela ?

Comment: E preciso que a função execute apenas quando eu modificar o usuario.

Comment: Desta maneira que está escrita, onde tem tabela eu preciso colocar "nome db.tabela" ?

Comment: Sim consegues? e se quiseres fazer um trigger convém declarar "nome db.tabela", mas tenta nao fazer mais perguntas em comentários mas cria uma nova pergunta, pois é aconselhado nao responder com comentarios ;) e toda a gente fica a ganhar